# Is any countable set a metric space?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

As per the definition of metric space (Rudin): 
[image: Rudin's definition of metric spaces]
Here is what I understand: Any countable set $A$ can be mapped 1-1 to the set of natural numbers. Let $n(x)$ be the natural number to which any element $x$ belonging to $A$ is mapped. Define the distance function, $ d(p,q) = |n(p) - n(q)|$ for any element $p$ and $q$ belonging to A. This satisfies conditions $ (a),(b)$ and $(c) $. Therefore any countable set should be a metric space.

Is there another way to reason this?

Comment: Indeed, every set can be given a metric, just set $d(x, y) = \begin{cases}1 & x=y \\ 0 & x\neq y.\end{cases}$

Comment: Thank you. That clarifies, because that's I guess the simplest way of defining the distance function while still satisfying all the required properties. You meant the opposite, right? That is, d(x, y) = \begin{cases}0 & x=y \\ 1 & x\neq y.\end{cases} ? Because as per the definition $d(x,y)$ has to be >0 for unequal x and y, and 0 for equal x and y.

Comment: Yes, that's a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit tricky. A countable set is just that: a set. A metric space is a set *equipped with some distance function*. What you have shown is that for any countable set, there exists some metric on that countable set. But there are plenty of metrics on that set, and not all of them are "equivalent" (homeomorphic for example).

For example you could have put the discrete metric on your set by letting $d(x,x) = 0$ and $d(x,y) = 1$ for $x \neq y$. This satisfies all the axioms of a metric. In fact this works for any set, not only countable ones. But you could also have chosen a bijection between your set and $\{0\} \cup \{1/n \mid n \ge 1\}$, and use this bijection to define a metric. The possibilities are endless.

So to reiterate, I think the key point is: a set is just a set. Any set (including countable ones) can be equipped with *some* metric. Different metrics yield different metric spaces. So it's not really fair to say that "any countable set is a metric space": what is true is that any countable set can be equipped with some metric.

Comment: Why is being referred to as "tricky"?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Because some people have trouble with the idea that $\mathbb{R}$, for example, is a set but also has a metric and so on that comes with it. Then these people ask questions like "do I have the right to put another metric on $\mathbb{R}$", as every set either had or hadn't a metric and that was fixed for all eternity. They don't see the set and the metric space as separate entities.

Answer (score 2):

A metric space is not just a set.

A metric space consists of two ingredients, the first one is of course the set of points $S$. The second is the distance function $\delta: S\times S\rightarrow \mathbb R$.

It is not reasonable to say that a set is a metric space without specifying a distance function.

---

Every set $S$ can be given at least one distance function that makes it into a metric space, the function $\delta(x,y)=1$ if $x\neq y$ and $\delta(x,x)=0$ does the trick, it is called the discrete metric.

Answer (score 0):

A metric space S is a triplet (S,d,T) where d is a metric on the set S and T is the topology generated by the open d-balls. It is common, and accepted, abuse of notation to speak of "the metric space (S,d)" or "the metric space S".  Just as a topological space is a pair (S,T) where T is a topology on the set S but is often called "the (topological) space S."  A topological space (S,T) such that (S,d,T) is a metric space for some metric d on S is called a metrizable space. And is often called "the metrizable space S".